# Get today's date with specific timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I'm using [this datetime picker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) and want to set the minDate to today at 8 am.

The timepicker has the attribute `minDate` that can take input like `new Date(2012, 05, 15, 8, 00)`. I would like it be able to do something like `new Date(getFullYear(), getMonth(), getDate(), 8, 00)`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please accept an answer if your problem has been solved to show the other stackoverflow-users, that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `Date` object ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)) with the current date/time and then adjust it to your needs like the following, before passing it on to the datetime picker.

```
var minToday = new Date();
minToday.setHours( 8 );
minToday.setMinutes( 0 );
```

Note that this uses the local time of the user, which may be different from your server time!

Comment: Was just about to write this answer :) - here's a fiddle to show it works: http://jsfiddle.net/aXhzy/

Answer (score 3):

You need to get today's date first using

```
var today = new Date();
```

Then call those methods on `today`.

```
new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDay(), 8, 00)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... if you have to do all the calculations when you pass it as a param try

```
(function(){var d = new Date();d.setHours(8);d.setMinutes(0);d.setSeconds(0);return d;})()
```